# Can't toggle alarms and reminders permission

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-12

I have app which set alarms. I use this code to ask user for permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
"android.settings.REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM",
 Uri.parse("package:"+ getPackageName())
);
 someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

In manifest I added permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

When I click the button which launch the intent I can see:

[image]

But I can't toggle button with permission and I don't know why.

Comment: It is so until you set Unrestricted battery mode in Android settings for your app. And this all is bad for user. Did you manage to do something?

Answer (score 2):

It will return `isGranted = true` when the permission is being requested the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

And actually, the intent is `Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), (ActivityResult result) -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {}
        });

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2)
void hasPermission(@NonNull Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2) {

        // it depends on the manifest permission, just alike the toggle does.
        if (! alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {

        }

        // one can only disable the permission, when the manifest requested it.
        startActivityForResult.launch(new Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())
        ));
    }
}
```

Listen for broadcast action [`AlarmManager.ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED).

And there's also permission [`USE_EXACT_ALARM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_EXACT_ALARM), when targeting API `33` onwards.

See behavioral changes: [exact alarm permission](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exact-alarm-permission).